CUPS printing server issue (with HP DeskJet 1050A)
I want to make my HP DeskJet 1050A printer accessible on my home network.
I installed CUPS on my Ubuntu server, added a printer, which is connected to a USB port on my server (an old laptop), with a "HP DeskJet" driver.
When I tried to print something, the admin panel was showing that the job is complete, but nothing came out of the printer and the printer itself seemed that it didn't receive anything.
I decided to install HPLIP and changed the driver to one that was made specifically for my printer, but there came out another issue. CUPS panel has shown an error next to all of my jobs "stopped Filter failed".
I've ran out of ideas and there isn't any post or tutorial that helped me solve this problem. The only thing I know, that it might be a server-printer communication problem.
System: Ubuntu Server 22.04

What version of Ubuntu are you using? Please edit the question and add this info.
